# Is possible to request a iphone/Ipod/Ipad coordinates from server code?

Tags: c#, iphone, mobile

Exists a way of request a device for his coordinates from the server code (Ex: C# .NET)?

Comment: I honestly hope that the answer to this one is a resounding "no", otherwise I'd have to burn my iPhone :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear. You need to clarify on what platform you want. Perhaps you are getting things mixed up.

Do you really mean to run a server on an iPhone using C# code?!? I don't know anyone who's coded a webserver for an iPhone in C#, if that's what you really mean. (But it is possible for someone or a team to do this.)

But more likely you mean you want a C# webpage, running on a webserver to get a client's device coordinates, where the client device is an iPhone. But in this case, I don't believe C# has much to do with it, because this would be the webpage which would do the request, which would be HTML and JavaScript, not C#.

Comment: I have a Asp.net application (Developed in C#) and in his codebehind I try to request for the Iphone device coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

i think what Edward means is "No". :P